# Jenkins trigger call/build on other projects plugin not evaluating my env var

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my Jenkins job, I have "Execute shell section" where I am declaring new variables and adding values to it say for e.g installdir=/work/homes/x".

Following this section i have a "Trigger call/build on other projects" section. I am calling another project and I want to send this installdir to it as a predefined parameter. I have turned on the "current build parameters" and "predefined parameters". In predefined paramters, i have given install_dir=$installdir.

But its not evaluating this. How can I make it evaluate this installdir variable.

FYI: I have to set this installdir to different path based on user input. So execute shell is the only place I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Parameterized Trigger Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

UPDATE: See comments thread for info, the parametrized trigger plugin does not work for this particular use case.

Comment: I do use paramterized trigger plugin to get the input from the user.If the user enters input A and input B, i need to manipulate that and create a new variable C.. say C=A+B and then pass this new C to the other job. But it is not evaluating $C in predefined paramters

Comment: I see. It may be that variables created during a shell or batch build step are not pushed up to the higher level environment where the parameterized step would look. You could potentially work around this by adding $C as a user parameter but leave it blank by default. You could then assign a value during the shell step and that value should be picked up and passed on by the parameterized trigger plugin. This is not ideal obviously, but if you just need it to work it should do the trick.

Comment: I would also confirm that you have everything set up correctly by passing $A or $B to the next job and confirming that it is correct.

Comment: :If I pass $A or $B directly it works fine. I also thought about creating a dummy C as a parameter and gave it a value X as input. BUt in my shell, I change C=$A+$B. If I now pass $C to predefined parameters, it takes the value of $C as X and not $A+$B

Comment: Per this thread, it looks like that is the expected behavior. http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Modified-parameter-How-Parameterized-trigger-handle-it-td2312087.html

Comment: I could have sworn I had done this before though. As one user in the thread noted, you could create a properties file and pass that to the next build, but it's kind of a hacky way to do things.

Comment: I would encourage you to create an answer detailing how to use the properties file and mark that as accepted. This will help others who may need the same thing in future. As it stands, my answer is not really useful in the context of this question and probably shouldn't be marked as accepted (I do appreciate it, but this is about giving others a real solution for their problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the parameters for the triggered job using a ***generated properties file*** passed to the Parameterized Trigger Plugin. For example:

1. Create String parameter:

   - Name: `TRIGGER_JOB`
   - Default value: `my_git_project`
2. Create a Multistring parameter:

   - Name: `TRIGGER_JOB_PARAMS`
   - Default values:

     ```
     # Pass parameters to the triggered job with evaluated variables:
     GIT_PULL_BRANCH=${GIT_PULL_BRANCH}
     EMAIL_LIST=${EMAIL_LIST}
     ```
3. Add a Conditional Step (useful to trigger the next job only if requested):

   - Type: Execute shell

     ```
     # Will run TRIGGER_JOB (with TRIGGER_JOB_PARAMS) unless the value is empty:
     [[ -n "${TRIGGER_JOB}" ]] && \
     echo -e "${TRIGGER_JOB_PARAMS}" > TRIGGER_JOB_PARAMS.PROPERTIES
     ```
   - Steps to run if condition is met:

     - Trigger/call builds on other projects:

       - Projects to build: `${TRIGGER_JOB}`
       - Parameters from properties file:
         `TRIGGER_JOB_PARAMS.PROPERTIES`